# Simple SQL problem (mysql)

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT username, (SELECT follow 
                  FROM follow 
                  WHERE follow_user_id = user_id) AS following
FROM user
WHERE user_id = 1
```

I want to know how I can check if follow (sub-query (select follow ...)) returns a value. If it did, then replace it with 'yes'. If it didn't, then replace it with 'no'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT u.username, IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM follow f WHERE f.follow_user_id = u.user_id),"yes","no") FROM user u WHERE u.user_id = 1

Answer (score 7):

Use a case statement

```
select username, 
  Case When Exists 
      (select * from follow 
       where follow_user_id = user_id)
    Then 'Yes' Else 'No' End following
from user
where user_id = 1
```

Comment: This was faster than my solution in the test case I did, voted this one up.

0.34 sec instead of 0.42 sec (for about one million rows in each table on my desktop).

Comment: Yes, Exists stops reading data as soon as it finds a single row.... Count(*) has to.... well... count ALL the rows.